# Consume expanded EntitySet in UI5 without GetEntiySet Implementation

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, sap-gateway

I'm new in UI5 and I'd like to read an EntitySet **without** implemention of Get EntitySet

```js
oModel1.read("/LinesSet?$expand=ToCells&$filter=IdQuery%20eq%20%27ZSMKPI_QM_TOTAL_USERS%27", {
    success: function(oData) {
        console.log(" expand");
    },
    error: function(oError) {
        console.log("errooooooor expand");
    }
});
```

Error message :

> errordetails":[{"code":"/IWBEP/CX_MGW_NOT_IMPL_EXC","message":"Method
>   'LINESSET_GET_ENTITYSET' not implemented in data provider
>   class.","propertyref":"","severity":"error"}]}}} -

It's not implemented. I want to skip this method and consume `$expand` directly.

Comment: I assume this question is no longer relevant since you apparently can now use `$expand` according to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43255561/5846045). If so, please consider to close or removing this question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by creating Association and Navigation between the entity sets.