# ODataModel passing "expand" parameter in read

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'd like to pass expand parameters to [`read`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#read) because it doesn't work if I call the service like this:

```
oModel1.read("/LinesSet?$expand=ToCells", {
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`read` API awaits a map of options](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/read) as a second argument in which we can define any query using the property `urlParameters`:

```js
oModel1.read("/LinesSet", {
  urlParameters: {
    "$expand": "ToCells",
    "$select": "LineID,ToCells/CellID,...", // reduce data load
  },
  filters: [ // Filter required from sap/ui/model/Filter
    new Filter({/*...*/}), // reduce data load
  ],
  success: this.onSuccess.bind(this),
  // ...
});
```

⚠️ Please note that loading large amounts of data significantly affects memory consumption and UX negatively. This might even lead to crashing the application altogether ultimately. See the section [Loading Large Amounts of Data](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/966d67c8cc5046419d1b35556cd9e447) from the documentation.

> Whenever you use methods like [...] `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#read` [...] in application code, **your application must not load large amounts of data.**

⚠️ `read` is a low-level API from the application's point of view. There are other APIs and approaches that can help reducing the amount controller code.

---

## *Alternative (better) solution*

I'd like to emphasize that `v2.ODataModel#read` is often **not** required. You can simply make use of the OData Context/ListBinding by assigning the corresponding name of the `<NavigationProperty>` to the control in XML:

```xml
<Table binding="{ToThatRelatedSingleEntity}" items="{ToThatRelatedCollection}" growing="true">
```

<sup>(**Note:** You might have to add `templateShareable` to the aggregation binding accordingly as explained in the topic: [Lifecycle of Binding Templates](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/3a4a9e562988456c9be0ef883ae7da50))</sup>

**The binding**, not the application, will then prepare a request automatically for you. No need to use an intermediate `JSONModel`. Same with `v4.ODataModel` which doesn't even have the `read` method.
This makes also migrating to OData V4 much easier.

Comment: Thanks to @boghyon-hoffmann! The alternative solution looks great! It change the way of thinking. I wander what about the logic I want to add to success/error possibilities?

Comment: @A.B You can attach handlers to loading state events from Binding such as `dataRequested`, `dataReceived`, etc. **or** to ListBase events `updateStarted` and `updateFinished`. You can discern the error state when the `data` parameter of the `dataReceived` event is `undefined`. See my related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48443967/5846045