# SAPUI5: How to set service url parameters in runtime?

Tags: sapui5

I have an OData service which is made in `manifest.json`

In some services I need to pass some url parameters like `?$expand=XYZ`

SO the question is how can I set `serviceUrlParams` in the run time and not inside of the `manifest.json` while the OData model has been created by component class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ODataModel passing "expand" parameter in read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255561/odatamodel-passing-expand-parameter-in-read)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a misunderstanding that parameters such as `$expand` belong to the `serviceUrlParams`. No, we need to distinguish between

- *Metadata URL parameters*: `metadataUrlParams` in model definition. Those parameters will be only attached to the `$metadata` request which is at the model instantiation.
- *Service URL parameters*: `serviceUrlParams` in model definition. Those parameters will be attached to **all** requests.
- *Data URL parameters*:

  - `parameters` in binding definition (usually in the view) as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44901517/5846045), or
  - `urlParameters` in model APIs such as `read` as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43282067/5846045).

For `$expand`, data request parameter is what you have to define in each binding definition whereever it's needed. Then, the respective data will be loaded **on-demand**.

---

API Reference: [ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel)
Documentation: [ui5.sap.com/#/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2)

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will helps.

```
var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
oModel.read("/entityset?$expand=" + dynamicValue,mParameters);
```

Comment: I tested. The problem is that sapui5 removes $expand form the path.

Comment: @Martin @Sriram: In order to be able to use `expand` in the read method, you can use [`urlParameters` in the option map](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#read) and pass `"$expand": "ToXYZ"`.
[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43282067/5846045) is my answer using expand in read.

Answer (score -1):

for expand url data use the second parameter of the read function.

```
oDataModel.read("/yourEntitySet", {
    success:jQuery.proxy(this._yourSuccessCallback, this),
    urlParameters: {
        "$expand": "YourExpandData"
    },
    error: jQuery.proxy(this._yourErrorCallback, this)
});
```