# SAPUI5 Expand the model in the manifest

Tags: model, sapui5

I want to add a new model to the manifest.json.
The model is supposed to be expanded.

```
https://myPath/services/myService.xsodata/SubPath?$expand=CustomerRef
```

So the Datasource is defined:

```
"dataSources": {
    "mainService": {
        "uri": "/myPath/services/myService.xsodata/",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
            "odataVersion": "2.0",
            "localUri": "localService/myService.xsodata/metadata.xml"
        }
    }
```

And the model is defined:

```
"models": {
    "Customer": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
        "settings": {
            "useBatch": "false"
        },
        "dataSource": "mainService"
    }
```

How can I add the expand to the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data cannot be expanded in the model definition itself. The [`expand` parameter](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding) is to be used where the binding between the view and data is defined as [mentioned in the documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2#loio6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2):

> Some of the parameters must not be included in every request, but **should only be added to specific aggregation** or element bindings, such as $expand or $select. For this, the binding methods provide the option to pass a map of parameters, which are then included in all requests for this specific binding.

Here is an excerpt from the **example https://embed.plnkr.co/wAlrHB/**:

```xml
<List items="{
  path: 'odataModel>/Products',
  parameters: {
    expand: 'Category, Supplier',
    select: 'ProductName, UnitsInStock, Category/CategoryName, Supplier/Country'
  },
  sorter: [
    {
      path: 'Category/CategoryName',
      group: true
    }
  ],
  filters: [
    {
      path: 'Supplier/Country',
      operator: 'EQ',
      value1: 'UK'
    }
  ]
}">
  <ObjectListItem title="{odataModel>ProductName}" number="{odataModel>UnitsInStock}"/>
</List>
```

The **binding** (not the model) will then [send a request](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2#loio6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2) ...

> Requests to the back end are triggered by list bindings (ODataListBinding)

... with the respective parameters appended by UI5:

```xml
https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$format=json&$skip=0&$top=100&$orderby=Category/CategoryName%20asc&$filter=Supplier/Country%20eq%20%27UK%27&$expand=Category%2c%20Supplier&$select=ProductName%2c%20UnitsInStock%2c%20Category%2fCategoryName%2c%20Supplier%2fCountry
```

⇒ [JSON response](http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$skip=0&$top=100&$orderby=Category/CategoryName%20asc&$filter=Supplier/Country%20eq%20%27UK%27&$expand=Category%2C%20Supplier&$select=ProductName%2C%20UnitsInStock%2C%20Category%2FCategoryName%2C%20Supplier%2FCountry&$format=json)